# How to send my additional Intent data to Dialer / Phone application and receive those intent data in Another application service

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent

I created one sample phone app just dial a entered number like " `Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL,Uri.parse("tel:"+9090909090);`" able to call the dialed number.

I have create one service to get the phone state [Ringing or idle or offhook]. Am able to receive the proper state.

Now i need to differentiate the incoming call is dialed from device phone application or using my sample phone application. How can i achieve this ?

I tried with "`intent.putExtra("CALL_KEY", "CALL_VALUE");`" but am unable to receive a value :

```
intent.getStringExtra("CALL_KEY");
Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
bundle.getString("CALL_KEY");
```

Both returns the NULL value.

Please help me to identify in my service the phone call is made from my sample app or from default phone app ?

Comment: Any other option to share the data between two devices. ? 

Please advise me any suggestion on this ? ? Am in need !  ! !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My Query similar to this :

[Android: Can you send/receive data along a phonecall?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5989591/android-can-you-send-receive-data-along-a-phonecall)

I find the one way to send the information to the other device , but still am finding difficulty to receive the data.

Tried with extractNetworkPortion and extractPostDialPortion , but still getting NULL at receiver end.

Help me ! How can i receive data along with a phonecall ?