# Designing an autodialer that has a one way interaction with an automated phone service

Tags: voip, phone-call, modem, dtmf

I gave searching the archives the old college try but I couldn't find anything that really answered my question so here goes.

I am trying to design a simple autodialer.  Perhaps there are commercial and freeware programs that already do what I need this to do but I haven't found them yet, or they don't advertise the functionality that I need.  In one sentence, I need the autodialer to report in information to a phone service.  For more detail, my autodialer program needs to do the following:

1. **Read an input file** - This input file will be generated by another program. The input file will change many times a day, but at regular times, so the dialing program will need to run automatically after the input file is updated.
2. **It only needs to call one number, ever.**
3. **The number its calling is an automated number**. i.e. "Enter your ID number", "Enter your pswd", "Hi Hal, what is the airt temp?", "what is the water level?", "How big are the waves?"
4. **The program needs to interact with the phone service, but only send info**. Its a one way interaction, it does not need to receive info.  It can be a pretty "dumb" interaction (i.e. call number, wait/sleep for 10 seconds, enter ID number, wait 5 seconds, enter password, wait 4 seconds, enter the temperature....).
5. **This interaction/ information it sends to the phone service will be from the input file.**  The phone service has a navigation tree and the program need to work its way through it depending on the information in the input file.  I guess I need to send DTMF tones to the phone service.  [Android: Can you send/receive data along a phonecall?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5989591/android-can-you-send-receive-data-along-a-phonecall)
6. **I cannot change the phone service**.  I would love for the phone service to read my input file and cut out the middle man, but I can't do it.  Already tried.

I'm not a great programmer but I can program in a few languages.  I am most comfortable with Python but my poking around found some examples that people scripted in C#, C, and C++, so maybe I need to brush up on those.  An older post on Stackoverflow recommended using Skype4py but I'm not sure that is supported anymore by skype.

I'm not quite sure how to approach the placing of the phone call.  Should I do this over VoIP?  Should I use an old fashioned modem?  Do they sell modems anymore?  Does Matthew Broderick still have his from War Games and can I borrow it for a while?  Which language is good at initializing a modem and placing a call?  I'm looking for simplicity, don't need flash.  Most autodialers that I found were built to call lots of different phone numbers quickly, I'm assuming for telemarketers or call centers, but I couldn't find one that really does anything after the call is placed.

If you can give me any direction it would be very much appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve these requirements using a combination of two WC3 open standards; [Call Control XML (CCXML)](http://www.w3.org/TR/ccxml/) and [VoiceXML](http://www.w3.org/TR/voicexml20/).  You use the CCXML to make the outbound call to the phone service and determine when the phone is answered. Once the CCXML determines that it is answered it can pass control to a VoiceXML application.  The VoiceXML application can integrate with a database or file to determine which steps it needs to take to interact with the phone service.

To send the DTMF digits to the phone service you just play them as prompts.  Most VoiceXML platforms use WAV audio files for playback.  You can [get pre-recorded DTMF signals as WAV files here](http://evolution.voxeo.com/library/audio/prompts/dtmf/index.jsp).

An excellent CCXML/VoiceXML platform to test this out on is [Voxeo Prophecy](http://evolution.voxeo.com/).  You can download a two port system for free or develop for free on their cloud service. Their support is excellent and they will help you during your development/testing phase.  They have good [documentation on how to use CCXML for outbound dialing](http://docs.voxeo.com/ccxml/1.0-final/). Look at section *F Outbound Dialing*.

CCXML and VoiceXML are based on web standards so you can use your favorite web development languages and tools, such as ASP.NET and C#.  There is a good [open source project called VoiceModel](http://voicemodel.codeplex.com/) which abstract VoiceXML to a higher level, making it easier for ASP.NET MVC developers to create VoiceXML applications. You might want to look into this project for developing your VoiceXML using C#. There are plenty of examples. Have a look at the [Dynamic Menu Example](http://kevin-junghans.blogspot.com/2012/12/dynamic-menus-with-voicemodel.html) to see how you would read in some meta-data (such as your file) and dynamically create a voice application call flow.

The phone service you are interacting with is an [IVR System](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interactive_voice_response). Basically you are building an IVR System to interact with another IVR System, which a lot of IVR developers do to load test their IVR applications. So I know it is feasible. What you need to find out is if the IVR application on the phone service was developed to use barge-in. Barge-in is a feature which allows the caller to interrupt the recording that is being played back by the IVR to enter some input (DTMF or voice).  If barge-in is on then you do not have to worry about the timing in your IVR application and you can play the DTMF almost immediately. If barge-in is off then you will have to figure out the length of the recorded prompts and put pauses in your application so that the DTMF is played back at the correct time. Note that the barge-in may not be consistent for the whole application, some areas may use it and others may not. The only way to determine this is by calling the phone service yourself and trying it out.

You can put pauses in your application by playing back recorded silence. I have never used this software, but [here is one that generates silence WAV files](http://www.softpedia.com/get/Multimedia/Audio/Other-AUDIO-Tools/Silence.shtml) of varying length. You can also use WAV editors to create these audio file.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use custom tokens offered with ICTBroadcast that will exactly fulfill your requirments and will play your custom and personalized inforation to list of contacts automatically, please visit followingg for more detail

http://www.ictbroadcast.com/creating-personalized-messages-using-custom-tokens-in-email-campaign

Regards